# Show ticker text without a notification

Tags: android-layout, notifications, push-notification, android

I have a requirement i my project. We want to show a text in the status bar where we have time and network signal icons. But we don't want to have notification. the text just display, scroll as usual and then disappear completely. There should be no notification in the panel. Any idea how to achieve  this? I know there is no straightforward way to do this. Can any one provide any hack ??

**Update:**

I am able to generate notification and cancel it after some time. For this i have created a handler and cancel it after some time. But the problem is now to calculate time based on text size. I want to cancel the notification only when it completely rolled out.

```
final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setTicker("abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);




        mNotificationManager.notify(SharedPreferenceUtil.getInstance()
                .getNotificationId(context), mBuilder.build());

        Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Utility.Log("Notification Removed", Log.VERBOSE);
                mNotificationManager.cancel(id);
            }
        }, 10000);

        Utility.Log("Notification Posted", Log.VERBOSE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it

**You set the notification like this:**

```
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

**And After that you can remove from the notification list like this**

```
NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationmanager.cancel(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried posting notification, and instantly dismissing it?

Comment: Yes i have tried it but the problem is it shows only that text which can reside in one line on status bar. If i have a text which would come in 3-4 line in status bar then it will show only one line. After that it disappear.